# asp.net mvc save checkbox value to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have a simple mvc project consisting of one table named Persons and that table has some attributes like name, age, surname and so on.

I Recently added an attribute to table which is type of `bit` in SQL and `bool` in C# and for me it represents some status. If it is ok I put that status to true or false.

In one controller I create an index view of my Persons in the database and I display the status as a checkbox.  That is working ok.  What I want to do is to change the status if I click on that checkbox instead of using an edit view for all of the atributes.
I just want to save checkbox value from my index view to database.

Some people advised me to create an action in my controller like so:

```
public ActionResult Save(int id, bool status){}
```

Where `id` is `id` of my person in db and `status` is a value of the `checkbox` I clicked.

So how do I call that function with jquery, ajax or javascript and send those params?
I am not so good with ajax and a little bit afraid of it :)

And one more thing I manage to show checkbox value corectly from my databse only in this way:

```
@Html.CheckBox("somename", item.Status)
        <input name="somename" type="hidden" value="false"/>
```

Any help or advice or sending me to good direction is good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options. One way would be to place the checkboxes in a (normal) form and then use the [jQuery Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to Ajaxify the form:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.Checkbox(...)
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').ajaxForm({
            success: Saved,
            error: HandleError
        });
    });

    function Error(response, status, err) {
        // code to handle error here
    }

    function Saved(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
        // code to handle succes, if any
    }
</script>
```

You could, of course, use an `@Ajax.BeginForm` as well, but this has the advantage of being easily downgradable. Just remove the jQuery form initialisation and you got yourself a regular form : )

Another possibility is to simply use an `@Ajax.ActionLink`. I wrote a [blog post on how to deal with `Ajax.ActionLink`](http://www.sharpedgesoftware.com/Blog/2011/02/27/dealing-with-javascript-or-json-results-after-an-ajax-call-with-ajaxactionlink-unobtrusive-ajax-and-) that I think will help you out.

The signature for your controller action on your question looks correct:

```
public ActionResult Save(int id, bool status){}
```

Another options is actually to create a `Settings` view model (call it what you will), and in there just have a bunch of `bool` properties to represent the checkboxes:

```
public class Settings
{
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    // more properties here
}
```

then you can bind your action to the Settings object:

```
public ActionResult Save(int id, Settings settings){}
```

This will come in handy in case you end up having multiple checkboxes to bind.

Comment: using ajax actionlink seems to me like good choice so i could set ajax.action link on my checkbox and then call action and send params?
I am reading your blog post and trying to figure is it possible to use it with my function, in actionlink i can send id and checkbox value?

Comment: @GoranB - The problem with `ActionLink` in this case is that you'll need a "Save" link *for every checkbox*. This might not be too bad if you only have the `status` checkbox but can get quite cluttered if you have more. And passing the value of the checkbox dynamically could get tricky too, I'm thinking...

Comment: i have status and one more checkbox also from db, so if you could write an example of actionlink on checkbox and how to send params?

Comment: @GoranB - In that case I'd definitely recommend using the `form` method, either with the jQuery Form plugin or with `@Ajax.BeginForm`.

Comment: Thank you, although i didn't use all advices you give me, you point me to right idea and i use it, i managed to complete my task without form, only using html.actionlink, it works great i just need to add for my next bool var.