# How to save checkbox checked values in Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [asp.net mvc save checkbox value to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974727/asp-net-mvc-save-checkbox-value-to-database)

How to save checkbox values in database.

Below is my view code.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)    
{    
    @Html.CheckBox("statecheck", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["StatesList"])
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.state_name)    
    </br>    
}
<input class="ASPbutton" type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

Below is My controller.

```
public ActionResult States()  
{
    ViewData["StatesList"] = new SelectList(am.FindUpcomingStates().ToList(), "state_id", "state_Name");

    return View();   
}
```

My model is

```
public IQueryable<state> FindUpcomingStates()
{
    return from state in Adm.states orderby state.state_name select state;
}
```

After clicking submit button checked item `state_id` will be saved into database.

I wrote like below in Controller, but I got true or false values, I want `state_id`

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult States(string _stateName, char[] statecheck, FormCollection formvalues)
    {    
       statecheck = Request.Form["statecheck"].ToArray();
       ViewData["StatesList"] = new SelectList(am.FindUpcomingStates222().ToList(), "state_id", "state_id", _stateName);
    }
```